# Trouble reading from a file, and using the data from the files in my program

Tags: c, io

In this program I have a file called 'accounts.dat' and in this file there are some lines of data like

```
1000:first
2000:second
3000:third
```

But when I tried to fscanf the data values into my arrays in my program I get:

```
0:$ s·°Ïÿ¿
1:t·¨BuÞZ·
-1217025816:s·0s·É¥s·hp[·4£s·
```

As the values scanned, or at least thats what it's showing.

My function to scan the values is:

```
void read (int accounts[MAX], char debcred[MAX], double amount[MAX], char accname[][MAXSTRING], char transname[][MAXSTRING], int *i) {

FILE *fp1 = NULL;
//FILE *fp2 = NULL;

fp1 = fopen("accounts.dat", "r");
//fp2 = fopen("transactions.dat", "r");

int h = 0;



if (fp1 != NULL) // READING THE FILE
{
    while(fscanf(fp1, "%d", &accounts[h]) != EOF)
    {

            fgetc(fp1);
            fscanf(fp1, "%30[^\n]", &accname[h]);
            h++;

            printf("%d:%s\n", accounts[h], accname[h]);

    }

    fclose(fp1);
}
else
    printf ("Failed to open file\n");

}
```

And how I call my read function in my main is:

```
read(accounts, debcred, amount, accname, transname, &i);
```

And my declarations in my main function is:

```
int accounts[MAX], accounts2[MAX], account;
char debcred[MAX], accname[MAX][MAXSTRING], transname[MAX][MAXSTRING];
double amount[MAX];
```

Can anyone figure out what my problem is? Why aren't the data lines in my file being scanned into my arrays in my program properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> fscanf(fp1, "%30[^\n]", &accname[h]);
> h++;
> printf("%d:%s\n", accounts[h], accname[h]);
> ```

Try incrementing `h` **after** you print.

Comment: ... and using a sensible `for(h=0 ; ; h++) {...}` loop instead of "manually" incrementing the loop index is a way to avoid this kind of errors.